# Why is the behavior when assigning to values inconsistent?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Consider the two DataFrames `d1` and `d2`:

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(2).reshape(-1, 2), columns=['A', 'B'])
d2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[0], B=list('a')))
```

I want to overwrite the first column of `d1`.  It starts off as:

```
d1

   A  B
0  0  1
```

I attempt to overwrite the values of `'A'` with:

```
d1.values[:, 0] = 2
d1

   A  B
0  2  1
```

However when I do the same thing with `d2`, I get different results.

```
d2

   A  B
0  0  a
```

Then:

```
d2.values[:, 0] = 2
d2

   A  B
0  0  a
```

Nothing has changed, except when I do:

```
d2.A.values[:] = 2
d2

   A  B
0  2  a
```

---

Why is this behavior inconsistent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of the mixed `dtype`s in `d2` you'll get an `object`-array (copy) when you access the whole `.values`.

```
>>> d2.values
array([[0, 'a']], dtype=object)
```

This happens for any non-identical datatypes, e.g. also for `int32` vs. `int64`:

```
>>> d2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=np.int32([0]), B=np.int64([0])))
>>> d2.values[:, 1] = 3
>>> print(d2)
   A  B
0  0  0
```

The changes only propagate back if the dtype is exactly the same for all columns:

```
>>> d2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=np.int32([0]), B=np.int32([0])))
>>> d2.values[:, 1] = 3
>>> print(d2)
   A  B
0  0  3
```

---

Just to give an (approximate) way to find out if it's a view or a copy of the actual column you could use [`np.shares_memory`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.shares_memory.html#numpy.shares_memory):

```
>>> np.shares_memory(d1.values, d1.A.values)
True

>>> np.shares_memory(d2.values, d2.A.values)
False
```

Comment: Yes, pandas normally keeps them in separate blocks (int in its own array and object in its own array) but when you call the values attribute, it creates a numpy array (a copy) when the dtypes are mixed.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the internals but could it be that pandas stores the dataframe as ND-array in case all dtypes are the same (otherwise it just keeps the columns as 1D array)? That would explain how it could return a view at all.

Comment: It has a thing called [BlockManager](http://www.jeffreytratner.com/slides/pandas-under-the-hood-pydata-seattle-2015.pdf) (pp. 36-39) that is responsible for arranging different dtypes. Each block has its own numpy array under the hood. So for example with `d2.A.values[:]` pir is directly accessing the numpy array which holds the int64 values. It's the same with `d1.values[:, 0]` because that's also the exact int64 numpy array that pandas stores.